# IN MVC6 return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) ISSUE

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

IN MVC6 return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  method is changed and not allowing to set JsonrequestBehavior. What is alternative in MVC6

Comment: I am retruning json reuslt form my controller. it works with mvc4 by setting sonRequestBehavior.AllowGet .In MVC6  i am not able to set this beahviour...

Answer (score 7):

That overload of `Json` method which takes JsonRequestBehavior does not exist in the aspnet core any more.

You can simply call the `Json` method with the object data you want to send back.

```
public IActionResult GetJsonData()
{
  var rows = new List<string>  {  "Item 1","Item 2" };
  return Json(rows);
}
```

Or even

```
public IList<string> GetJsonData()
{
    var rows = new List<string>  {"aa", "bb" };
    return rows;
}
```

or using `Ok` method and having `IActionResult` as the return type.

```
public IActionResult GetJsonData()
{
   var rows = new List<string>   { "aa",  "bb"  };
    return Ok(rows);
}
```

and let the content negotiator return the data in the requested format(via Accept header). The default format used by ASP.NET Core MVC is JSON. So if you are not explicitly requesting another format(ex :application/xml), you will get json response.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult List()
    {          
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

        return Json(rows, settings);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData()
{
  var data= //your list values
  return Json(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JsonRequestBehavior is deprecated from ASP.net core 1. Just use return Json();